# I want a regular expression to describe integer from -32768 to 32767

Tags: regex

I reached the following regular expression:

```
[-]?\b(?:-[1-9]|-3276[0-8]|-?[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|-?[12][0-9]{4}|-?3[01][0-9]{3}|-?32[0-6][0-9]{2}|-?327[0-5][0-9]|[0-9]|3276[0-7])\b
```

However, I am capturing `-0`. How do I solve it?

Comment: Add `(?!0\b)` after the first `\b`

Comment: Are you trying to match `-32768` inclusive? It's not matching that as it stands.

Comment: Which regex engine/language?

Comment: Does `-?(?:[12]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,3}|3[01]\d{3}|32[0-6]\d{2}|327[0-5]\d|\d|3276[0-8])(?<!-0)\b` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that `\b` at start doesn't match the minus sign. If you replace it with a custom boundary, it works:

```
(?:^|[^0-9-])(?:-[1-9]|-3276[0-8]|-?[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|-?[12][0-9]{4}|-?3[01][0-9]{3}|-?32[0-6][0-9]{2}|-?327[0-5][0-9]|[0-9]|3276[0-7])\b
```

See an [example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uhShGx/1)